# Jsoup error 502

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to login to a website (intranet page with some subsystems), enter in a subsystem, search something and parse the page.

I can login, but when I try to access the subsystem I receive an HTTP error 502. However in the browser opens normally.

I think that is some problem with a proxy (which is already set in java). After some few tries my login is blocked and I get the HTTP error 407 (page blocked or something like that)

I already tried to put `.useragent("mozilla...")`, `.timeout(...)`, `.ignorehttperrors(true)`, `ignorecontenttype(true)` and using `.cookie` too.

Is there some way to solve this?

```
Response x = Jsoup.connect("page").data("...").method(method.GET).execute();
```

---

I used the given suggestion (apache httpclient and I don't get the HTTP errors anymore.
But I still want to know if jsoup can bypass this problem, because I could use just one .jar instead 6 (5 from apache plus jsoup to parse the responses.). Thanks to those that who edited my post (rs) and to ollo for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you connect through socket or HttpClient?

Comment: I'm not used to httpclient, I will test,after discover how, to make the connection. I'd rather use just jsoup...

Comment: JSoup has only a very simple connection api. If httpclient works you better use this (download the website and parse it with jsoup). Also can try the java URL connection API.

Comment: Btw. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using Java's `UrlConnection`:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("your url").openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy server");
connection.addRequestProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxy port");

// Alternative:
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "yourproxyserver");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "portnumber");

InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();

// Read response into buffer and parse it with jsoup
```

See also my answer here: [JSoup over VPN/proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288471/jsoup-over-vpn-proxy)

*(i guess thats a better one)*

But i realy reccommend you *HttpClient* (or a similar one) for such connection things. As i said before, jsoup as only a limited connection support.

Comment: As I mentioned before,I did the connection with HttpPost and just with System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "yourproxyserver");.

I'm closing this question, since there don't appeared answers to this.