# Connect to vpn with credentials using python script

Tags: python, vpn

I have the python script which extract data from a server and stores the same in Google sheet. The only problem here is that that server cannot be accessed without vpn. I have the vpn credentials but I don't know how to do that.
Is connecting with vpn from python code is possible? How?

Comment: What have you looked for so far? I'm not sure if this a duplicate- but looks almost similar: [SO- How to VPN/Proxy connect in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144685/how-to-vpn-proxy-connect-in-python)

Comment: That's on the os level, I need to push this code on airflow so I was finding something to direct connect with the vpn.